# How can I import a file while executing a content script in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to execute some javascript so I have my background.html page set up like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script>
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "contentscript.js"});
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would really like to use JQuery in this script, but I can't figure out how to get it to load. I don't want the content script to go off every time the user loads certain pages, just when they click the extension's button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.tabs.executeScript` method has third parameter which is a callback function that executes when a script is loaded, which you can use to load more than one script in order:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "jquery.js"}, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "contentscript.js"});
    });
});
```

You don't need to include `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>` into your  background page if you don't plan using it there.